# Check network signal with phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I just want to know that, Can we develop Phonegap app which will check if network connection is present for windows phone? The requirement is

1) Application will continuously check for signal after specific time (eg. 1 min)

2) If network signal is not found it will vibrate mobile or trigger alarm

So user will take action to regain signal.

Please let me know can this is possible for windows phone using phonegap

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Connection Plugin: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

```
    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    }
```